# Postman extension setting an environment variable from response headers or body

Tags: postman

Postman extension had a feature of setting an environment variable from one of the values from response headers or body. It is missing after update. Can someone help here.

Answer (score 8):

You can set the environment variable from response body/header as follows:

**From Response Body:**

```js
var body = JSON.parse(responseBody);

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("[environmentVariable]", body.variableName);
```

**From Response Header:**

```js
var headerName = responseHeaders.headerName;

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("[environmentVariable]", headerName);
```

Answer (score 3):

For **Postman extension on Chrome** latest version (*by posting time*) **version 4.8.3** [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en).

Everthing is working fine regarding setting an environment variable programatically in either `Pre-request script` section or `Tests` section.

For more info, check docs [here](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/sandbox).

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, I'll leave this here as an update:

to set a variable from response body ( JSON ):

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.environement.set("your_var", jsonData["the_value"]);
```

and to get it from a header:

```
var value = pm.response.headers.get("the_header");
pm.environement.set("your_var", value);
```